# How to manage the private key of the owner of the Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am a junior developer developing smart contracts for Ethereum.
We receive money from other companies to develop Dapps.

Smart contracts contain features that can only be used by the owner.
Owner's private key is required to use this function.

The company that commissioned us to develop does not want to expose the owner's private key.
Our company that develops also does not want to hardcode the private key into the database or source code.

Is there any way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where you as the developer don't even need to know the `owner` private key.

- Deployer can be a different address from the owner. I.e. you can deploy the contract from your address, and set the client's `owner` address in the constructor.
- The owner can interact with the smart contract using their own wallet (e.g. MetaMask or a hardware wallet through WalletConnect) that holds the private key for them. In this approach, they need to manually sign every transaction going from the owner address.
- The client can also self-host the app, passing the private key only in their own instance.

Or if you need to hold their key, hold it in a secrets management system such as Hashicorp Vault or AWS Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

> The company that commissioned us to develop does not want to expose the owner's private key. Our company that develops also does not want to hardcode the private key into the database or source code.

Set [Gnosis Safe multisig wallet](https://gnosis-safe.io/) as the owner of the contract. It will allow you to configure owner setups at the beginning and it the future. This is what everyone else is doing in this industry.